# Bad Request - 400 when using Azure Add Data Disk REST API

Tags: rest, azure

I am building a Java app to automate some typical infrastructure tasks in my application. I successfully calling the Azure API, but I get a (400) Bad Request return code/message. I'm debugging this in eclipse, but can't find any more meaningful data in the connection object.

The initial simple task I'm trying to do is to add a new Data Disk to my IaaS VM, 'gildev01'.  I'm following the guidance in this documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj157199.aspx

The HTTPS URL is correct, starting with management.core.windows.net followed by my Subscription ID, then the following:

/services/hostedservices/gildev01/deployments/gildev01/roles/gildev01/DataDisks

The payload is as follows:

```
<DataVirtualHardDisk xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/windowsazure" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<HostCaching>ReadWrite</HostCaching>
<DiskLabel>java-disklabel-1</DiskLabel>
<DiskName>javadisk1</DiskName>
<LogicalDiskSizeInGB>1000</LogicalDiskSizeInGB>
<MediaLink>http://<myacct>.blob.core.windows.net/vhds/javadisk1.vhd</MediaLink>
</DataVirtualHardDisk>
```

So - two questions:

1) any ideas on what I'm doing wrong with the URL or the payload?

2) any suggestions on how to get more info out of the response object?

Adding Java Code:

```
private String addDataDisk (URL url, String keyStore, String keyStorePassword) throws UnrecoverableKeyException, KeyManagementException, KeyStoreException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, IOException {
 SSLSocketFactory sslFactory = getSSLSocketFactory(keyStore, keyStorePassword);
 String requestBody = "<DataVirtualHardDisk xmlns=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/windowsazure\" xmlns:i=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\"><HostCaching>ReadWrite</HostCaching><DiskLabel>java-disklabel-1</DiskLabel><DiskName>javadisk1</DiskName><LogicalDiskSizeInGB>1000</LogicalDiskSizeInGB><MediaLink>http://myacct.blob.core.windows.net/vhds/javadisk1.vhd</MediaLink></DataVirtualHardDisk>");
 HttpsURLConnection con = null;
    con = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    con.setSSLSocketFactory(sslFactory);
    con.setDoOutput(true);
    con.setRequestMethod("POST");
    con.addRequestProperty("x-ms-version", "2013-08-01");
    con.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", String.valueOf(requestBody.length()));
    con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/xml");

    DataOutputStream  requestStream = new DataOutputStream (con.getOutputStream());
    requestStream.write(requestBody.getBytes());
    requestStream.flush();
    requestStream.close();

    String responseMessage = con.getResponseMessage()+" - "+Integer.toString(con.getResponseCode());
```

Comment: Are you creating an empty data disk or trying to create a new data disk using an existing VHD? Also I'm guessing you're writing the code in Java. Can you share the code?

Comment: creating an empty data disk - actually, assuming you are the same Guarav founder of Cynapta - this is came from your blog and worked for simple start/stop vm ... trying to add code

Answer (score 0):

Yep, same guy :)

Based on the documentation:

> Option 1 – Attach an empty data disk to the role by specifying the
>   disk label and location of the disk image.
>
> - **Do not include the DiskName and SourceMediaLink** elements in the request body.
> - Include the MediaLink element and reference a blob that is in the same geographical region as the role.
> - You can also omit the MediaLink element. In this usage, Windows Azure will create the data disk in the storage account configured as
>     default for the role.

**Can you try by removing the `<DiskName>` element from your request body and see if that works?**

Also not sure how you would do this in Java but when you get a 400 exception, if you parse the response body, you should see detailed error message. For example, in .Net we do something like this:

```
        catch (WebException webEx)
        {
            using (var resp = (HttpWebResponse)webEx.Response)
            {
                using (var respStreamReader = new StreamReader(resp.GetResponseStream()))
                {
                    var errorMessage = respStreamReader.ReadToEnd();//errorMessage will be XML containing detailed error message.
                }
            }
        }
```

**UPDATE**

So I just tried creating an empty data disk using the API, and I get 400 error under two situations:

1. If I don't set the content type to `application/xml`.
2. If I include `<DiskName>` element in my request body. Once I removed this element, I was able to successfully create a data disk. So your request body should not contain this element.

**UPDATE 2**

Endpoint: `https://management.core.windows.net/<subscriptionid>/services/hostedservices/<cloudservicename>/deployments/<deploymentname>/roles/<rolename>/DataDisks`

x-ms-version: `2013-08-01`

XML Request:

```
<DataVirtualHardDisk xmlns=""http://schemas.microsoft.com/windowsazure"" xmlns:i=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"">
<HostCaching>ReadWrite</HostCaching>
<DiskLabel>java-disklabel-1</DiskLabel>
<LogicalDiskSizeInGB>1000</LogicalDiskSizeInGB>
<MediaLink>http://account.blob.core.windows.net/vhds/javadisk1.vhd</MediaLink>
</DataVirtualHardDisk>
```

Comment: wow - love your blog! ... so I tried to remove both the DiskName and then the MediaLink tags and still got bad request.  As far as I can tell, it's the con.getOutputStream method that would throw an exception - that only throws an IOException and that didn't happen when I put in a try/catch.

Comment: Just remove the DiskName and leave the MediaLink tag.

Comment: sorry - probably didn't make it clear:  I tried removing DiskName first and leaving MediaLink that didn't work.  Then I tried removing both - still didn't work.

Comment: That should have worked. Does the storage account specified in the media link element belong to the same subscription?

Comment: Guarav - would you be able to share your URL and request xml?  also - did you set your x-ms-version to '2012-03-01' or to a later date?

Comment: Updated my answer with the things you asked for. HTH.